# Where is the seem in my proof?

Tags: calculus, geometry

I tried to derive the area of a circle using proper calculus, but when I did so, I messed something up and got $A = 2 \pi r^2$, which is obviously wrong, but I can't figure out why this derivation fails.

Suppose there exists a circle with radius $r$.  The area of this circle can be represented as the sum of its sectors, where, when the circle is divided into $n$ sectors, each with area $A_m$, $A_{total} = \sum_{i=1}^n A_i$.

The area of a sector may be approximated by a rectangle whose sides are the arc length of the sector and the radius, meaning $A_{\theta} \approx \theta r^2$.  When $\theta = 0$, this approximate becomes accurate as a line segment may be thought of as a rectangle, in this case with dimensions $0 \times r$.  Therefore:
$$A_{total} = \lim_{||\theta|| \to 0} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \theta r^2$$
$$= \int_0^{2 \pi}r^2d \theta $$
$$= \theta r^2 \bigg|_0^{2 \pi}=2 \pi r^2$$
What happened?  Why doesn't this derivation work?

Edit: I understand the approximating the area of a sector as a triangle with $base = \theta r$ and height $r$ is better, but why does the rectangle based derivation I did fail?

Comment: Sorry, where does the formula $A_{\theta}=\theta r^2$ come from?  If $\theta=2\pi$, isn't the sector the whole circle?

Comment: "The area of a sector may be **poorly** approximated by a rectangle whose sides are the arc length of the sector and the radius." The better approximation is by an isosceles triangle whose base is the arc length and height is the radius; the area of that triangle is $\frac{1}{2}\theta r^2$. Continuing from there, the proof gets the expected result.

Comment: The area of a sector $A_{\theta} \approx \theta r^2$ comes from approximating the area of the sector as a rectangle of dimension $\theta r \times r$.

Comment: The following picture uses rectangles to compute the area of a circle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_of_a_circle#/media/File:CircleArea.svg and neatly shows why you have an extra factor of 2!

Comment: *How* are you "pasting" together the rectangles?   Okay one side is the sector $\theta$; what are the other three sides?  You can't use a radius because that isn't perpendicular to the sector side.  And two radii are parallel to each other  You could take perpedinculars but they will not pass through the center.  and what is the side opposite the sector length.  You just can't cut a circle this way.

Comment: Okay.  Let's try this with $n=12$.  What is our first rectangle.  It goes from (0,0) to (1,0).  Then from (1,0) to (1,sin 30) then... (1,sin 30) to (0, sin 30) and (0, sin 30) to (0,0).  That's the first rectangle.  What's the second?  You can't do (0,0) to (cos 30, sin 30) because that has overlap.  You can't do (0, sin30) to (cos 30, sin 30) because that isn't equal it area to your first.  Basically you don't have any *model* of how to do this.  If you don't have a *model* you can't actually do this.  This like assuming you can tesselate pentagons and not acknowledge that you can't.

Answer (score 3):

Your are trying to estimate the area of the circle by adding up the areas of the rectangles.

[image]

But the area of the circle is *not* the sum of the rectangles.

It just *isn't*.  It's not that it is *better* to do it with triangles.  It's that it is *possible* to do it with triangles.  It is not *possible* to do it with rectangles.

The rectangles don't add up to the circle.

Answer (score 2):

Simple: the initial formula is wrong. The area of a small sector can be approximated by the area of a *triangle*, with vertex  at the centre of the circle. The formula for the area of a triangle is half the area  of your rectangle, so there remains no factor $2$.

Comment: I understand that, but why does the rectangle proof not work?

Comment: What you need is an *equivalent* – in the mathematical sense: the ratio must  tend to $1$, not a loose approximation such as physicists can make. The rectangle does not satisfy this requirement, but the triangle does.

Comment: The rectangle approximation doesn't work because the error in estimating the area of the sector is too large.  Let $S_n=\pi r^2/n$ be the sector area and $A_n$ the approximation, then the approximation error $n(S_n-A_n))$ needs to go to zero for the approximation to converge.  With the rectangle the error is of the order of $\theta$ and $n\theta\rightarrow 2\pi\neq 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, whereas for the triangle the error is of the order $\theta^2$ and $n\theta^2 = (2\pi)^2/n \rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ and therefore the argument is correct with the triangle calculation.

Comment: It's not just that the error is large.  It's that the rectangles overlap so that area of the circle isn't just the area of the rectangles plus the "rounding error"... the area of the circle is the area of the rectangles minus the area of the overlap.  The overlap is *huge*.  This just doesn't approximate a circle at all.  There is simply not correlation to the rectangles and a circle.  None at all.

Comment: The overlap, as you say, is  the area of the triangle, whence the factor $2$.